# Random walk and definition of Stochastic Processes

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, self-learning

Why random walk is considered a stochastic process?
Definition of stochastic processes assumes that each random variable is based on the same probability space.

If we consider random walk:
$$X_{n}=V_{1}+V_{2}+...+V_{n}$$ where $V$ are bernoulli random variables then probability space of $X_{1}$  is different than probability space of $X_{10}$, $X_{10}$ can take different values than $X_{1}$

Comment: You consider all the 'values' that $X_n $ takes for some fixed $n $ normall (eg positiom after $10$ steps). So you are right.

Comment: So what is definition of random walk? Sequence of $X_{n}$ defined as above? And such thing is not a stochastic process?

Comment: Whose definition of stochastic processes assumes that each random variable is based on the same probability space?  See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/a/17617/6460 In any case, all your $X_n$ take values in the integers (though some with probability $0$)

Comment: Yes, the sum of the $V_i $'s.

Comment: I am only talking about a random walk which is a very basic type of stochastic process.

Comment: http://stat.math.uregina.ca/~kozdron/Teaching/Regina/862Winter06/Handouts/revised_lecture1.pdf Henry, I interpreted it in such way, It seems I am wrong, thanks for explanation and valuable link ;)

Comment: You should look at the general definition and then ask more specific questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The random walk is considered a stochastic process because it is ;-)

Usually you use the "infinite coin toss" for modelling a random walk and then the problem doesn't occur so take

$\Omega = \left\{\omega = (\omega_1, \omega_2, \ldots), \omega_i \in \{0,1\}, i\in\Bbb N \right\} = \{0,1\}^\Bbb N$ and $V_i(\omega) = \omega_i$

with $V_i$s are bernoulli random variables.

Then $X_n(\omega) = V_1(\omega) + \ldots + V_n(\omega)$ and all r.v. are defined on the same probability space…